# How to design an API backend request that might take too long

Tags: python, rest, flask, backend

Let's say I have an API endpoint that generates a PDF file with lots of images sent by the client.

The server can try to estimate how long it will take by getting the images sizes before downloading them, but it can't factor in busy/slow network spikes.

So, obviously, the server just returns an "Ongoing" signal, and send an email or something when the file is done, right?

But what if the user sent a very small sample of images and sending an email is unnecessary? Is it possible to factor this with certainty? Can the server calculate that this file ended up so small that it can definitely send it directly without getting a time out from the browser?

I'm new to full-stack development but I believe this must be a common issue, is there a name to this? 
What are common workarounds and solutions for this issue considering that :

1) Sending an email to the user is not an ideal solution

2) Streaming the file during its creation is not possible.

3) Processing should be halted if the user gives up/closes the browser/loses connection/etc.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting that the connection is no longer active should be fairly easy. So why don't you just check if the connection is active when you have finished rendering the file and if it's still active send it right back. If it's not then you can email the file. Additionally, if you are in the process of sending the file back and the browser times out then just email the file.

As far as estimating all of these things, there are no perfect solutions for how to estimate these things. It's impossible for you to know if someone is using your website on their mobile phone in the subway and suddenly goes into a tunnel losing all service.

Comment: I didn't know the server could detect a closed connection on a non web socket request

Comment: @Mojimi you'll certainly get an error if you attempt to write into a socket that's closed. And I guess I should clarify that all communication that a server does goes through a socket (not a web socket but a normal server socket). If you look up how to implement a basic web server you will see that most serving libraries are just abstractions built on top of sockets.

Comment: Well for servers like flask (the one I'm using) I'm really not sure if it's possible, as the response is always the return value of the wrapper router function, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Check out this GitHub issue https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/2702

Answer (score 1):

One option which could simplify the need for your client to deal with differing response codes and formats is to have your API return a `HTTP 202 (Accepted)`, and returning an `id` which represents the resource ID of the new PDF.  In this scenario, the API can respond immediately and do any asynchronous processing required to create the PDF.  The client can then query for the resource from your API via a separate endpoint such as `GET /pdf/<id>`.  If the PDF is still being processed, your API will just return a 404 until it is complete.

If you would prefer to not have the client continuously poll the API, you could define a certain threshold of time you're willing to wait before defaulting to sending an email.  For example, start a timer as soon as the API is called and begin generating the PDF, if the timer exceeds the threshold you're willing to accept, return a `HTTP 202` and optionally send an email after the processing finishes.  In the case where the PDF generation finishes before the time threshold, return a `HTTP 2xx` with the PDF file in the response.

Comment: Do you know of any javascript libs that do this?

Comment: I would suggest looking at Promises in JS, they offer a pretty straightforward way to implement a continuously polling async callback: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises